# unable to connect to mongodb on localhost

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB:

```
user@user-workshop:~$ sudo service mongodb restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
mongodb start/running, process 7980
user@user-workshop:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
Mon Mar  3 21:43:33 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
user@user-workshop:~$
```

but as you can see, I'm unable to connect to it. What can I do about it?

Comment: Look at your system error logs

Answer (score -1):

Try running these commands:

rm /data/db/mongod.lock

mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair

mongod --dbpath /data/db

For more details read: [mongodb manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)